# Need formula to get lowest and highest value of a year

Tags: php, loops, date

```
$how_many_years = 8;

//loop
for( $i = 1; $i <= $how_many_years; $i++ ) {    
    //...
    array(
        'id'       => 'year-'.$i.'-min',
        'default'  => '1',  // first day number of the year

    )
    array(
        'id'       => 'year-'.$i.'-max',                    
        'default'  => '364',  //last day number of the year             
    )

}
```

Right now, these `default` arguments (1st year: 1-364, 2nd year: 365-729, 3rd year: 730-1094) aren't dynamic in the example above.

What kind of formula (function) can I use inside this loop to generate the right (begin/end) day number for each year?

Comment: real years? do you need to consider leap years with 366 days?

Comment: @tim, leap year is 366 days

Comment: @user1597430, lol yeah thanks

Comment: The date function can actually be ignored, it's more math. 1 and 364, 365 and 729, 730 and 1094  (min and max values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what array structure you want, but just do some math with `1` and `365`. I used `1` and `365` because there are `365` days in a year, ignoring leap year which you seem to do.  Since you're not using real years I'm not sure which one would be leap year anyway 1, 2, 3, 4, 5?

Just change `$max = 364` if that's what you really want:

```
$how_many_years = 8;
$min = 1;
$max = 365;

for($i = 1; $i <= $how_many_years; $i++ ) {
    print_r(array(
        array(
            'id'       => 'year-'.$i.'-min',
            'default'  => $min,  // first day number of the year

        ),
        array(
            'id'       => 'year-'.$i.'-max',                    
            'default'  => $max,  //last day number of the year             
        ))
    );
    $min = $max + 1;
    $max = $min + 365;
}
```

See the **[Example](https://3v4l.org/2U9vJ)**.